# help I changed one currency in woocommerce and everything is ruined

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, errors

I changed the line 545  `'MAD' => '&#x62f;.&#x645;.',)` of wc-corefunctions.php to `'MAD' => 'DH',` and now the page is full of errors 
how can i fix it please?

Comment: did you change it back?

Comment: Which version of woocommerce are you using? This is line 545 in version 2.1. https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-core-functions.php#L545

Comment: I'm using version 2.1 and i copied back the full php file, still it doesn't work

Comment: It's okay I fixed, the problem was that i tried to change currency in the Theme functions file + the woocommerce core file 
Thank you guys :)

Comment: Glad to hear. Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than attempting to modify a core file of woocommerce, make use of their filter hook. First of all, make sure you are using an up to date version of woocommerce.

From the woocommerce documentation [Add a custom currency / symbol](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/add-a-custom-currency-symbol/):

> To add a custom currency in WooCommerce 2.0+, copy and paste this code
>   in your theme functions.php file and swap out the currency code and
>   symbol with your own.
>
> After saving changes, it should be available from your WooCommerce
>   settings.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currencies', 'add_my_currency' );

function add_my_currency( $currencies ) {
     $currencies['ABC'] = __( 'Currency name', 'woocommerce' );
     return $currencies;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'add_my_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

function add_my_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
     switch( $currency ) {
          // Notice you are able to type the actual character instead of the hex value.
          case 'ABC': $currency_symbol = '$'; break;
     }
     return $currency_symbol;
}
```

That said, your code probably failed because you did not use the [hex value of the currency symbol](http://www.addressmunger.com/special_ascii_characters/) you are replacing it with. I believe it would be `'MAD' => '&#x62f;.&#x2e;.&#x625;.',` according to this reference on [currency unicode values](http://www.ip2currency.com/currency-symbol). There should not be a `)` at the end either. See [line 545 of `wc-core-functions.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-core-functions.php#L545)
.

Comment: i copied back the full original php file, still it doesn't work, is there anyway to get things back ?

Comment: It's okay I fixed, the problem was that i tried to change currency in the Theme functions file + the woocommerce core file 
Thank you guys :)